# c# how to read json when button is clicked, how to print to table after reading?

Tags: c#

I want to change my datagrid table, which I filled when the form is opened, by calling another json file with a button. how will I do? how to read json when button is clicked, how to print to table after reading?

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    parameters. Clear);
    dataGridView1.Refresh();

    string dosya_yolu2 = Application.StartupPath + "Files\\defaultValue.json";
    //Okuma işlem yapacağımız dosyanın yolunu belirtiyoruz.
    FileStream dv2 = new FileStream(dosya_yolu2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    //Bir file stream nesnesi oluşturuyoruz. 1.parametre dosya yolunu,
    //2.parametre dosyanın açılacağını,
    //3.parametre dosyaya erişimin veri okumak için olacağını gösterir.
    StreamReader sw2 = new StreamReader(dv2);
    //Okuma işlemi için bir StreamReader nesnesi oluşturduk.
    string yazi2 = sw2.ReadToEnd();
    //Satır satır okuma işlemini gerçekleştirdik ve ekrana yazdırdık
    //Son satır okunduktan sonra okuma işlemini bitirdik
    sw2.Close();
    dv2.Close();
    //İşimiz bitince kullandığımız nesneleri iade ettik.

}
```

Comment: You need to use a JSON serializer like JSON.NET or System.Text.Json, to read the JSON data as objects. After that, you can display them like any other object. Have you tried using a deserializer?

Comment: From Tony : *You have to deserialize the json data (create a model for that) and after that you can view it in data grid view control.*

Comment: Which stack are you using? WinForms? WPF? Which control? All stacks and many controls support data binding. Once you have a List<Whatever> you can display it on a grid by passing it to the grid's [DataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-a-windows-forms-combobox-or-listbox-control-to-data?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&preserve-view=true) in WinForms or `[ItemsSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-bind-to-a-collection-and-display-information-based-on-selection?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) in WPF

Comment: WinForms I use. i cleared previous json file from my table but i can't see new json file on screen

Comment: Post your code in the question. What you posted doesn't parse the JSON string. There's no code that tries to display the deserialized objects to any grid. If you use data binding, all you have to do is assign a new value to `DataSource`

Comment: Can you show me how to write a code that tries to display objects in any grid?

Comment: I posted the links to doc examples for WinForms and WPF

Comment: sorry with the examples in the link it doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/13.0.1?_src=template). Since you have not posted your json as a sample there are no guarantees what is presented below will work as is dependent on your json used.

The following json is used, in this case in the same folder as the executable named `Customers.json`.

```
[
  {
    "CustomerIdentifier": 1,
    "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste's",
    "ContactName": "Maria Anders",
    "Address": "Obere Str. 57",
    "City": "Berlin",
    "PostalCode": "12209",
    "Country": "Germany"
  },
  {
    "CustomerIdentifier": 2,
    "CompanyName": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
    "ContactName": "Ana Trujillo",
    "Address": "Avda. de la ConstituciÃ³n 2222",
    "City": "MÃ©xico D.F.",
    "PostalCode": "05021",
    "Country": "Mexico"
  },
  {
    "CustomerIdentifier": 3,
    "CompanyName": "Antonio Moreno TaquerÃ­a",
    "ContactName": "Antonio Moreno",
    "Address": "Mataderos  2312",
    "City": "MÃ©xico D.F.",
    "PostalCode": "05023",
    "Country": "Mexico"
  },
  {
    "CustomerIdentifier": 4,
    "CompanyName": "Around the Horn",
    "ContactName": "Thomas Hardy",
    "Address": "120 Hanover Sq.",
    "City": "London",
    "PostalCode": "WA1 1DP",
    "Country": "UK"
  }
]
```

Keeping code simple, the file is loaded in Form.Shown event, will work in a Button Click event also.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data;

namespace WinFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Shown += OnShown;
        }

        private void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var json = File.ReadAllText("Customers.json");
            DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
            dt.Columns["CustomerIdentifier"].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to deserialize the json data (create a model for that) and after that you can view it in data grid view control.

Comment: This should be a comment. SO is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum and answers should actually answer the question. The rule of 50 rep to comment is there so people can understand the difference between discussions and answers before they start commenting. With a bit more rep you'll be able to post comments. I've posted this comment on your behalf and flagged this for deletion